# Keyboard and mouse take a long time to respond on boot

Tags: boot, 16.04

I have recently installed ubuntu 16.04 but i am having some trouble with my mouse and keyboard taking a long time to respond on boot. I have uploaded the dmesg output to gist.

When in the grub menu the keyboard works fine. Once ubuntu boots and gets to the login screen i am unable to type or move my mouse for ~30 seconds.

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/901c50250fdfcd450c22c326e5d527be

`lsusb` gives the following

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:8001 Intel Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8009 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 005: ID 1b1c:1b27 Corsair 
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 058f:6387 Alcor Micro Corp. Flash Drive
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 1b1c:1b2f Corsair 
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 1b1c:1b15 Corsair 
Bus 003 Device 006: ID 046d:0825 Logitech, Inc. Webcam C270
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

and `xinput` gives the following

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Corsair Corsair STRAFE Gaming Keyboard    id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Corsair Corsair Gaming SABRE RGB Mouse    id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Corsair Corsair Gaming SABRE RGB Mouse    id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Corsair Corsair VOID Wireless Gaming Dongle   id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Corsair Corsair STRAFE Gaming Keyboard    id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ UVC Camera (046d:0825)                    id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Comment: Welcome to askubuntu! Could you define "long time" and perhaps add some detail? For instance do they not respond only at the grub menu or does the problem persist after the default boot entry in grub is launched? Please [edit] further info into your post in order to help us help you! Thank you!

Comment: Apologies for that. I have added the information.

Comment: Please also [edit] in the output of `lsusb` and `xinput`

Comment: I have also added that too. Sometimes the devices work on boot as expected and other times they don't. It seems intermittent.

Comment: Do you still have this issue? If not please accept the answer that was of most use to you or if you solved it another way, please [write a good answer](http://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-answer) so that others with the same issue can benefit from your experience. If you stil l have this problem, please [edit] your post and replace the output of `lsusb` with the output of `lsusb -tv` as it may be related to the driver in use on a particular bus.

Answer (score 0):

If I had the hardware in hand (as you do) I would begin by gradually reducing the number of components on USB Bus 3 and checking the results against previous experience.

In your case, it appears that the Keyboard and Mouse are USB devices and that a device on the USB bus 3 may be causing delays.

My first choice for removal would be the Alcor Micro Corp. Flash Drive as Flash drives are inherently slow and sometimes have problems mounting.

If I still didn't get acceptable results I would disconnect the USB Webcam and try again. (Simply because it appears to be the only other device sharing USB Bus 3 with your keyboard and Mouse.

If I still didn't get acceptable results I would try replacing the Gaming Keyboard and mouse with less sophisticated versions so as to measure the impact of that.

Whether or not you use the USB pass through on the keyboard might also have an impact. Narrowing the field of choices will allow for more in depth examination of root cause.

This approach should help you reduce your time spent waiting on the bus (pun intended) ;-)