# Typing extremely laggy in new 16.04 install

Tags: 16.04, dual-boot, keyboard, amd-graphics

Just added Ubuntu 16.04 dual booting with Windows 10.

When I type in any program it's extremely laggy. I have to type very slow or keystrokes are missed. The problem is intermittent; sometimes it's fine. CPU and memory usage look normal. I have not *noticed* other issues. I have reinstalled which did not help.

GPU is an AMD Radeon HD 6950. I have a feeling it might be driver related but I'm not seeing other problems that I would expect.

Thanks!

Comment: Related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/895037/keyboard-and-mouse-take-a-long-time-to-respond-on-boot/895062

Comment: @ElderGeek Thanks for the tip! It wasn't related to other devices, but having the keyboard on that specific bus screwed things up for whatever reason.

Comment: I'm glad you got it working. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I changed the keyboard to a port on a different USB bus and everything is fine now.

I can't say I know *why* this was happening. I experimented with different combinations of devices and ports and the only thing that affected the problem was if the keyboard was on that bus.

Comment: Knowing why might help others with this particular issue. The output of `lsusb -tv` would provide information on which driver is in use on a particular bus and the devices on that bus.